# Conflict of Laws: Single Jurisdiction

Tags: conflict-of-laws

I have attempted to learn what I can (IANAL) from reading the article: [Conflict of Laws Principles](https://www.upcounsel.com/conflict-of-laws-principles): Everything You Need to Know.

The article indicates multiple (2+ jurisdictions).

> Conflict of laws signifies the difference between the laws of two or
>   more jurisdictions that are applicable to a dispute in question. that
>   are applicable to a dispute in question.

If there are two conflicting state laws of the same jurisdiction (for example both in Florida):

- is nomenclature different (i.e. not "Conflict of Laws" and is labeled "XYZ")
- are the principles for determining which law applies the same with said Florida example

A good answer would walk through the thought process of the example provided at: [HOA meetings transcripts](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/51901/20892)

Comment: For what it's worth, it turns out the question about the HOA meetings isn't a representative example of the situation you're asking about here.  https://law.stackexchange.com/a/51964/12269

Comment: @A.fm  Could you please clarify why the reason why the HOA example is not representative?  Is it b/c your posting indicates an exception?  Thank you

Comment: Essentially, yes.  Your scenario speaks to a situation where two laws within the same jurisdiction conflict with one another.  In the HOA question/example, there are no laws presented which conflict with one another.

Answer (score 2):

"Conflict of Laws" refers only to competing jurisdictional issues, not laws within a single jurisdiction which appear to "conflict" with each other.

Competing jurisdictional issues arise where more than one jurisdiction applies. A good example is where a party resides in one state, but the subject matter of the lawsuit occurred in another state. How to decide the issue is a matter of continuing legal evolution. Your article is generally accurate as far as it goes, but there's many pages of legal opinion written as to what constitutes a procedural vs. a substantive matter.

With regard to different laws of a single jurisdiction, deciding which law applies is called "litigation." I'm trying to be funny, but I'm not joking. Legal and factual research combine to persuade a judge that the law more favorable to you is the one that should be applied.